# How to update --thread_stack value in AWS RDS MySQL instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We are getting following error on AWS RDS instance:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Thread stack overrun: 246160 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and 16000 bytes needed. Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

I did not find option to increase value for `thread_stack` on AWS console. We wanted to know if it is possible to update its value in AWS RDS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set `thread_stack` or any other non editable global variable via mysql prompt. You need to set variables value in AWS RDS Parameter Group and restart instance. Please note that you won't be able to edit default parameter group. You need to create one, update `thread_stack` and assign that parameter group to your mysql instance.

[image]